# How do I connect these meshes correctly?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to model a gun and its requiring me to connect the meshes. I'm using blender 2.83 beta.[image: cylinder on the left and the main mesh on the right]

Answer (score 4):

You should begin with the circular shape because it's the most convenient to do, then make a series of extrusions.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for clean topology, these are some ways to connect it.

[image]